# Cordova Release App to Play Store Issue

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I have generate a signed help.apk file but when I publish the app on the Play Store, I got a mail with this issue:

> The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.

**Edit:**

Freshly built project with File, File Transfer and Splash screen plugin added to it. Older versions of this app are already successfully in play store; I am just upgrading Cordova version and applying some minor fixes.

Android version - android 6.1.2
Cordova version - 6.5.0

Yet, google play rejected my app saying:

> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>   The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1. You can find more information and next steps in this Google Help Center article.

Can anyone help with the solution to this rejection?

Comment: It would be better to suggest which version of cordova r u using?? if You are using the cordova version below 4.1.1, then update cordova, build and place it in playstore.

Comment: hii naresh , i have checked cordova version its 6.5.0

Comment: What version of `cordova-android` do you have installed in your project -- that's what Google is checking. `cordova platforms ls` should show you. Also, double check that there aren't any spurious `cordova.js` files in your project structure (beyond what Cordova builds for you) -- those have been known to trip Google up in the past as well.

Comment: cordova android platform version 4.0.0

Comment: i have include  cordova.js file in our project , because its necessary , without that give error in console

Comment: thanks you guys for great response , now my issue fixed .  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your cordova-android platform to 5.X.X.

To Update cordova-android platform

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@5.x.x
```

follow this link for more details https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/20/security.html

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is posting correct answer, i'll add what works for me.
 Kerri Shotts comment helps me a lot. yes, you should look at your 'www' project more closely and remove previous 'cordova' js files inside it. Let the cordova build to add them.
Do necessary changes in your html files to use latest cordova.